# sqoop import in parquet format _success doesn't get generated

Tags: hdfs, sqoop, parquet

I am using sqoop to import data in parquet format, every thing works fine except _SUCCESS file doesn't generated in the target HDFS location.

```
bin/sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:[conn_string]' --table [table] --target-dir hdfs://hdfs-location/ --as-parquetfile
```

I need this _SUCCESS for creating Oozie bundle job

Answer (score 0):

`_SUCCESS` file is generated after successful import with following file formats:

- avrodatafile
- sequencefile
- textfile

For Parquet file format, you will get `.metadata` first and on sucessful import you will get `.parquet` files.